# Use DataTemplate-Content from resource

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

In my application I have a `HierarchicalDataTemplate` which looks like:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ParentDisplayTreeItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <CheckBox.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Image}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Display}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,1"/>
            </Grid>
        </CheckBox.Content>
    </CheckBox>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

And a `DataTemplate` which looks like:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ChildDisplayTreeItem}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <CheckBox.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Image}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Display}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,1"/>
            </Grid>
        </CheckBox.Content>
    </CheckBox>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see both have the same content with a `CheckBox`.

Is it possible to move the `CheckBox` to a resource and use it from there?

I've tried it to provide it as `ControlTemplate` in the resources like:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="CheckBoxControlTemplate">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <CheckBox.Content>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="16"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Image Grid.Column="0" Source="{Binding Image}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Display}" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="2,1"/>
            </Grid>
        </CheckBox.Content>
    </CheckBox>
</ControlTemplate>
```

And use it like:

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ParentDisplayTreeItem}" ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <StaticResource ResourceKey="CheckBoxControlTemplate"/>
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```

But I get a compile-error with this approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. It should look like this.

```
<HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:ParentDisplayTreeItem}" 
                          ItemsSource="{Binding Children}">
    <CheckBox Template="{StaticResource CheckBoxControlTemplate}" />
</HierarchicalDataTemplate>
```